# Consistent Freehand line in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I know how to draw freehand in opengl, but I'd like it to not have gaps if you move the mouse too fast. This is what I have:

```
void myMovedMouse(int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    int x = mouseX;
    int y = IMAGE_Y - mouseY - 1;
    //int brushSize = 20;
    //glRecti(x, y, x + brushSize, y + brushSize);
    drawDot(x, y);
    glFlush();
}

//in main
glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
glutMotionFunc(myMovedMouse);
```

I also tried to use `GL_LINE_LOOP`, but of course that didn't work.

Comment: BTW, You're not going to get too far with this approach, and it's going to get progressively slower the longer you "draw."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append mouse positions to a `std::vector` & use `GL_LINE_STRIP`:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector< int > points;
void mouse( int button, int state, int x, int y )
{
    if( state == GLUT_DOWN )
        points.clear();
    points.push_back( x );
    points.push_back( y );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void motion( int x, int y )
{
    points.push_back( x );
    points.push_back( y );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1 );
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    glOrtho( 0, w, h, 0, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin( GL_LINE_STRIP );
    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2 )
    {
        glVertex2i( points[i+0], points[i+1] );
    }
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutMouseFunc( mouse );
    glutMotionFunc( motion );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not allow gaps, if the author uses a mouse button. Also it looks like that he doesnt clear the color buffers, so there is a lot of performance lost, by redrawing. @WolvenOmega , can you elaborate on that (mouse button, color buffers?)

Comment: Could store lines (pairs of points) and use GL_LINES instead.

Comment: I don't clear the color buffers because I want to be able to keep the previous drawing and continue even if I "lift the pen" so to speak. Also as is, the program currently draws when either mouse button is clicked. After I get this part working, the right mouse button will clear the canvas.

Comment: If that is the case, then the method provided in this answer has not the optimal performance, because you will redraw the stroke every time. When you dont clear the color buffers, my answer will be magnitudes better in terms of performance.

Comment: I actually think this answer is what I was trying to accomplish earlier (before I completely changed my approach), I'm going to mess around with it a bit and see where that gets me first.

Comment: @WolvenOmega If your program will be similar to drawing software (photoshop, paint, etc.) i cant stress enough, that this is quite possibly the worst solution one could think of. You should keep your drawing in your buffer, and only modify what has to be modified. If you have problems understanding "my approach" (most drawing software do it this way), ask, i elaborate.

Comment: Honestly, all I really wanted was to be able to draw a curve with the mouse, and only clear the canvas when the right mouse button is clicked. I was able to use this answer to do just that; in `myMouse` (this answer's `mouse`), I set additional conditions. Only add to the vector if the left button is pressed, and if the right button is pressed, clear color buffer, `glFlush`, and clear the vector. As far as I can tell, it does exactly what I wanted it to do...

Comment: @MarioDekena Unless OP is targeting 20 year old hardware, I think he's fine with clearing buffers each frame. GPUs are specialized for this type of work, and it's better to invalidate the previous buffer than waiting on data you don't need.

Comment: @pleluron It depends. I referred to drawing software which apparently is not what the author was aming for. You are right, drawing a single stroke might not be a big deal, but imagine a drawing being rendered from the ground up every frame, stroke by stroke. That would really be a stupid thing to do. And by the way, GPU's are only as efficient as the programmer that uses it. Actually gpus are way more vulnerable to bad code then cpus... Anyway, glad the author found a solution that works for him.

Comment: @MarioDekena *"but imagine a drawing being rendered from the ground up every frame, stroke by stroke"* That's how every game and graphics-intensive app works.

Comment: @DavidLively Game objects can be drawn in parallel. A drawing would have to be drawn in sequence (bad) because the strokes (brush with blend mode, erasing) rely on previous information. There is also no reason, why you would want to rebuild the drawing even if you could efficiently draw it in parallel, because you only reproduce information you allready had. In a game you have to clear and redraw because old information (last frame) is almost completely useless. Studied [computational visualistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_visualistics), allready worked on game engines.

Comment: @MarioDekena that's not why we clear. Parallelism has nothing to do with it (DX11 and OpenGL are not thread-friendly, and every packet queued gets executed sequentially). This is the way the industry works. I'm sorry you find all of our efforts inefficient.

Comment: @DavidLively You dont use immediate mode for drawing. You put data inside buffers and let the gpu handle it to avoid sending vast amounts of draw calls. The parallelism obviously happens inside the gpu. I never said anything about multithreading at all. From what you have written, i cant tell if you actually know what you talk about. Only "this is how every app / industry works", without any details. Everyone with a little knowledge of graphics programming would agree with me about the "clear buffer and redraw in drawing app is stupid" thing. Lets stop here, this is not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

Save your mouse position from last update in a global variable. Then connect to your new location using a line. Something like this:

```
int lastMouseX, lastMouseY;

void myMovedMouse(int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    int x = mouseX;
    int y = IMAGE_Y - mouseY - 1;

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(lastMouseX, lastMouseY);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();

    lastMouseX = x;
    lastMouseY = y;
}
```

If you are using a mouse button for drawing, only update your last position when your button is pressed down. Also initialize the last position to the mouse position, when the button is pressed again. The initialization is needed, so your first stroke does not start form the origin (0,0) and further strokes wont connect to the previous ones.